# How to identify printer type in java?

Tags: java, printing

Is there any way to find out (in java) if particular printer is a dot matrix?

I'm getting the default printer using the `PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService ()` function, but I need to know if it's dot matrix, laser or inkjet.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: May I ask why you must know the specific type of printer? This currently sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thank you @VinceEmigh. Many of our customers use USB dot matrix printers, and for this they I need to send ESC-POS commands on the print ... but these commands cause problems with other printer types.